# matplotlib.pyplot takes too long to plot x tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Time Value
01-01-2018T10:54:42.1234 1.20
01-01-2018T10:55:10.1234 1.22
...
...
```

Where, Time is `datatime` instance.

And goes on for 2 months time (We are talking about 15k entries)
I'm trying to do a simple line plot like so:

```
x = Data['Time']
y = Data['Value']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

plt.xlabel(xlabel, fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel(ylabel, fontsize=16)

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.savefig(filename)
fig.clear()
plt.close(fig)
```

But it's taking an enormous amount of time to finish because it's trying to plot all of the x ticks in `x`.
Is there a way to remove the ticks before the `plt.plot`, or better yet, shorten the plotted labels to something like 01-01, 02-01, 03-01, etc... to save on execution time?

Comment: If your "Time" column is text, then you need to convert it to datetime first

Comment: @DizietAsahi it is datetime, but thanks for the observation, I should include it in the post

Comment: weird, even with 100k points, this plot only takes a couple of sec or so to display on my computer. Test code: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
N = 100000;
idx = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', freq='1min', periods=N);
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': idx, 'Value':np.random.random(size=(N,))});
plt.figure();
plt.plot(df['Time'],df['Value']);
plt.show();`

Comment: Yes, if the column was datetimes, there would be no problem. It must be some other type. Check what it is and convert it to datetime before plotting.

Comment: You can also do `Data.plot(x='Time', y='Value', ax=ax)`, still, you want your `Time` column to be `datetime` type`